# Display subcategories in HTML select box

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following categories displayed in a select box:

```
<form>
    <select class="favoritefood">
        <optgroup label="Dairy products">
            <option>Cheese</option>
            <option>Egg</option>

        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Vegetables">
            <option>Cabbage</option>
            <option>Lettuce</option>
            <option>Beans</option>
            <option>Onions</option>
            <option>Courgettes</option>

        </optgroup>
    </select>
</form>
```

Is there any way to go another level down, ie, a subcategory? I've tried using optgroup inside optgroup but it doesn't work.

Comment: <select> is pretty bare-bones. You may want to consider a List-based apprach, such as the one used in Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Answer (score 2):

Or just put one or more spaces - &nbsp - before your text in the option.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom dropdown for this purpose. Here are the steps:

1. Hide the original dropdown with CSS (display:none;) OR create a hidden field that will contain the value selected by the user

   `<input type="hidden" name="selection" id="selection">`
2. Create a unordered list (ul) with as many nested li and sub ul

   ```
   <ul class="custom-drop">
       <li class="option-group">
            <ul>
               <li class="heading">Vegetables</li>
               <li>Cabbage</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="option-group">
            <ul>
               <li class="heading">Dairy products</li>
               <li>Cheese</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
   ```
3. Style this newly created ul as per your needs
4. Listen for the `click` event on li inside this ul and set the appropriate option inside the hidden dropdown OR set the value of hidden field so that it can be sent with the form.

So if you are using jQuery then do something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.custom-drop li', function() {
    $('#selection').val($(this).text());
    // Probably you want to handle showing/hiding the custom drop here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried to follow the instructions, but it doesn't seem possible to transform the dropdown list from a ul. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/8BHNY/

Comment: This was just to lead you in the right direction of course you need to build upon this..

Answer (score 0):

You cant go any deeper. It is not allowed for the optgroup. 
Read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6